# Format text column as a date unless there is specific text

Tags: excel, formatting, transform, powerquery

I am new to Power Query.

I have a database, containing all text fields, to populate onto an excel spreadsheet as a requirement for business purposes. I am not allowed to add or delete tables in the spreadsheet. The problem I'm having is with the End Date column.

The End Date column can either have a date format or "TBD" as text if there is a start date but no end date.

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

Essentially I need power query to format the incoming in the End Date column as a date, unless the row contains "TBD". In that case I need the row to remain as "TBD". However as you can see from the picture above, it fails to populate correctly.

This is the formula I've been trying to get working but I haven't had any luck. Is there a way to accomplish this task?

= Table.TransformColumns(
_qryPerstat,{{"END DT",
each if *qryPerstat[END DT] = "TBD" then "TBD" else Date.From(DateTimeZone.From(*)), type date}})

[image: Getting Data from Database where "Error" is "TBD"]

Comment: You need `type any`, not `type date` since TBD is not a date.

Comment: This is the way